# Can you use the getstream.io js client with react native instead of react-native-activity-feed?

Tags: javascript, react-native, getstream-io

*Hi getstream community,*

I am building a feed application with react native and node.js. I am struggling to add activities using the getstream.io js client, but I can do it with react-native-activity-feed's `<StatusUpdateForm/>` component. I get the following error with the js client:

```
An error occured when submitting activity: Error: {"detail":"You don't have the permission to do this","status_code":403,"code":17,"exception":"NotAllowedException","duration":"0.16ms"} with HTTP status code 403
```

I've set up the backend to send me a user token and initialize a user feed:

```
      const streamClient = stream.connect(STREAM_KEY, STREAM_SECRET, STREAM_ID);
      gsToken = streamClient.createUserToken(decodedToken.user_id);
      streamClient.feed('user', decodedToken.user_id);
```

In the frontend I render a feed using `<StreaApp/>` & `<FlatFeed/>`

I've set up the post screen to send a sample activity on press to the feed:

```
    var client = stream.connect(config.stream.app.key, config.stream.app.token,  config.stream.app.id);
    var user_feed = client.feed('user', config.stream.app.userId);
    user_feed.addActivity({
      actor: config.stream.app.userId,
      tweet: 'Hello World I am finally here',
      verb: 'Tweet',
      object: 1
    })
      .then(function(data) { console.log('Activity Added! ' + data)})
      .catch(function(err) { console.log('An error occured when submitting activity: ' + err)});
```

**SideNote:** *I would like to use the js client instead of the react-native package so I can have more flexibility with UI.*

Answer (score 0):

When using user tokens please make sure to call `setUser`

```
let feed = client.feed("user", "jack");
await client.setUser({name: 'Jack'});

await userFeed.addActivity({
  actor: client.currentUser,
  verb: "post",
  object: "my object",
})
```

this will populate client.currentUser which you can use as actor as well as store the user data in the actor field.